# A problem on sequence of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose measurable functions $f_n$ on $[a,b]$ converge a.e. to zero. Are there numbers $a_n$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\infty$ but the sequence $a_nf_n$ converges a.e. to zero for any $f_n$?

I don't know how to construct the number sequence at all. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: No; the sequence $\frac{1}{a_n}$ goes to 0, just let $f$ be that.